# Stream filter by two parameters

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I have googled quite a bit, but didn't found an answer.
Here is what I have:

```
    parentList.forEach(p -> {
        childList
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> p.id() == c.parentId())
                .<...continue working on stream...>
    });
```

I cannot find a way how to replace "filter" part with a Predicate as it seems that I need to pass argument to Predicate?

Comment: What's wrong with the current `filter()` call?

Comment: If I plan to reuse this filter in other places - trying to avoid copy/paste. Other than that - nothing.

Comment: For a predicate that simple, it's not really worth avoiding the copy/paste. If you have a complex set of conditions to filter on, consider making a method that you can call in it's place, and then use `c -> someMethodComparing(c, p)`

Comment: @lucasvw Thanks, helpful comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a different Predicate each time, because although `c` is the parameter to your predicate, `p` also varies:

```
final Node p;
Predicate<Node> matchesParentId = c -> p.id() == c.id();
```

The reason your existing code compiles OK is that `p` is *effectively final* in the scope of the `forEach` block, so it can be used as a final field in a `Predicate` within that scope, with a lifetime of one `forEach` iteration.

You could do:

```
parentList.forEach(p -> {
    childList
            .stream()
            .filter(matchesId(p))
            .<...continue working on stream...>
});

private Predicate<Node> matchesId(Node other) {
     return node -> node.id() == other.id();
}
```

But you won't be able to create one `Predicate` and reuse it as `p` varies.

---

You could write a `BiPredicate` and [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) it into a `Predicate`. Unfortunately Java doesn't provide a curry method, so you have to provide your own.

```
private <T,U> Predicate<U> curry(BiPredicate<T,U> biPredicate, T t) {
    return u -> biPredicate.test(t, u);
} 

BiPredicate<Node,Node> nodesMatch = (a,b) -> a.id() == b.id();

parentList.forEach(p -> {
    childList
        .stream()
        .filter(curry(nodesMatch, p))
        .<...continue working on stream...>
});
```

This doesn't buy you all that much over and above the previous solution, but it's a bit more FP-nerdy. You're still creating a new `Predicate` for every `p`. Of course you could inline it rather than use the `curry()` method.

```
.filter(c -> nodesMatch.test(p, c))
```

It does mean you could have a selection of `BiPredicate<Node,Node>`s to plug in dynamically. If your `BiPredicate` were expensive to initialise, the many `Predicates` wrapped around it by currying would be cheap.

---

Or, you could map `p` and `c` into a single object, which allows you to submit the whole thing to a predicate:

```
Predicate<Pair<Node,Node>> nodesMatch = pair -> 
    pair.left().id() == pair.right().id();

parentList.forEach(p -> {
    childList
        .stream()
        .map(c -> new Pair<Node>( c, p))
        .filter(nodesMatch)
        .map( pair -> pair.left() )
        .<...continue working on stream...>
});
```

(`Pair` here is hypothetical, but a number of 3rd party libraries (e.g. Guava) provide one, or roll your own, or use `new Node[] { c, p }`)

Comment: Thanks, for help and for providing another way of doing it.